# Finding the closest location based on pre-defined working radius set within the same table

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find the closest locations of pre-defined entries within a table. So far, the query I am using works fine and provides a fairly accurate result set.

How it works is:  1 table contains pre-defined estimations from plumbers that set their estimated cost for a specific price range. However, each plumber has their own working radius that can be different to other plumbers. Here is an example.

Table:  Pre-Defined Quotation

```
ID     NAME     PRICERANGE     ESTIMATED-COST     WORKING-RADIUS    LAT    LONG
1      JOHN     £500-£800          £560             20 MILES        51.50   -0.118
```

My current query loops over the full pre-defined quotations table and will order the results by distance being closest first.

```
        $quotes = Quote::all()->where('latitude', '!=', null)->where('longitude', '!=', null)->where('estCost', '!=', null);
        foreach ($quotes as $quote) {
        $tableName = "quotes";
        $origLat = 52.5002721395; // Customers lat
        $origLon = -1.98032029216; // Customers long
        $dist = 45; // This needs to be dynamic like:  $quote->working_radius
        $query = DB::select("SELECT id, latitude, longitude, estCost, working_radius, 3956 * 2 *
                              ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)
                              +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(latitude*pi()/180)
                              *POWER(SIN(($origLon-longitude)*pi()/180/2),2)))
                              as distance FROM $tableName WHERE
                              longitude between ($origLon-$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69)
                              and ($origLon+$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69)
                              and latitude between ($origLat-($dist/69))
                              and ($origLat+($dist/69))
                              having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 25");
    }
    $json = json_encode($query);
    $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($obj); $i++) {
        echo "Distance is " . round($obj[$i]["distance"], 1) . " from est id:" . $obj[$i]["id"] . " <br />";
    }
```

The problem I have is that the query is using the variable  `$dist` to define the maximum distance from the customers lat/long that the plumber should be. This would be ok apart from I need this to be defined by the working_radius value set within the same table or the plumbers_profile table.

I am using laravel here and i have tried several different ways to find a solution but seem to be failing every time.

The basic way I can explain this would be that I need to select all the pre-defined quotes that are no further in "miles" than the value set for each plumber in the working_radius column.

Right now the query above will return the following example:

```
Distance is 4.4 from quote id:1617
```

In an ideal situation i need to assign the `$dist` variable something like this: `$quote->working_distance` because the working distance is different for every plumber and the customer should not be shown a pre-defined quotation for a plumber that does not cover the customer's location.

If I assign $quote->working_radius to the $dist variable the results are incorrect and are shown like this:

```
Distance is 3.1 from quote id:1508
```

However the plumber with id:  1508 only has a 2 mile working_radius and should not be shown. If I set `$dist = 2;` then that same plumber does not get shown, So the issue lays with assigning the `$quote->working_radius` dynamically and is failing to use the value set in the database to determine the result.

Maybe i am going about this the totally wrong way? As a learner i have tried my best so far so hopefully someone with better experience can provide a helping hand on this. Thanks.

**Updated (17/11/2016)**

After working on the code since posting my question i have come up with a solution that works however im not sure it works for the good or for the bad! Maybe i have gone to overboard and maybe i have overly complicated things by assuming this is more complicated than it actually needs to be?

```
$quotes = Quote::orderBy('working_radius')->where('latitude', '!=', null)->where('longitude', '!=', null)->where('estCost', '!=', null)->get();

    $userLat = 52.5002721395; // Random selected lat and long for demo -- this acts as the customers property location
    $userLong = -1.98032029216;
    $tableName = "quotes";
    $dist = 250;  // This is the maximum it can be through the app
    $query = DB::select("SELECT id, working_radius, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($userLat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($userLong) ) + sin( radians($userLat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )
            AS distance
            FROM $tableName
            HAVING distance < $dist
            ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 25");
    $json = json_encode($query);
    $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($obj); $i++) {
        $plumbers[] = array('distance' => round($obj[$i]["distance"], 1), 'id' => $obj[$i]["id"], 'working_radius' => $obj[$i]["working_radius"]);
    }

    foreach ($plumbers as $plumber) {

        if($plumber['distance'] <= $plumber['working_radius']){
            var_dump($plumber);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully i have done things half right? As a learner im trying to self educate at the same time as progressing on with the app! Thanks.

Comment: Just use the sql field for distance in the formula, not a php variable. Are you ware that MySQL has built-in support for spatial data types and functions?

Comment: @Shadow - I have been doing some research and trying to self educate myself, One images i have been looking to deep into the querys and perhaps the obvious is stearing me in the face, I guess as a learner i may have missed something the MySql could have helped with much easier? Since asking the question i have been working on the code.. I will post a solution i have come up with, I assume i have over-complecated my function to be honest and i hope someone with more experience can provide a better opinion.  I will post my solution and search for the spatial data types.

Comment: @Shadow - What is you're opinion of the solution i have posted, Am i heading in the wrong direction and need to do some research on Spatial data types and learn more on mysql as apose to using php to perform the tasks?

Comment: We get it. We get it. Good grief; you like to talk! If it was me, I'd get rid of all of the above and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query instead. That said, you're revised query looks like the right sort of thing.

Comment: ...except, wouldn't it be `distance < LEAST(working_radius,$dist)` ?

Comment: I understand the quetion has grown somewhat out of context, that said i wanted to try and give people an understanding of what the issue was i had and to help anyone in the future whom has a similar issue, Sometimes short and sweet questions dont always do the justice.

Comment: Im not the best with sql so ill do some research into adding < LEAST(working_radius,$dist) but it looks much simpliar then doing further php checks!